# Magento2 composer for component is not working

Tags: magento2

I am  trying to upload all my media files of module by composer.

The problem is it is not uploading properly, it is creating pub directory inside the pub folder twice and uploading all files there but it should be inside pub/media/

The structure this is creating is:

[image]

I have tried with by mapping pub/media/* in pub/media

But this doesn't works at all.

I tried creating a composer file like this :
[image]

and directories to upload are in following hierarchy:

pub/media/ves/
pub/media/wusiwyg/